# Extracting country information from description using geograpy

Tags: python, geolocation, country, sanitization, geograpy

**PROBLEM:** I want to extract country information from a user description. So far, I'm giving a try with the geograpy package. I like the behavior when the input is not very clear for example in Evesham or Rochdale, however, the package interprets some strings like `Zaragoza, Spain` as two mentions while the user is clearing saying that its location is in Spain. Still, I don't know why amsterdam is not giving as output Holland... How can I improve the outputs? Am I missing anything important? Is there a better package to achieve this?

**DATA:** My data example is:

```
                   user_location
2  Socialist Republic of Alachua
3                Hérault, France
4                 Gwalior, India
5                Zaragoza,España
7                     amsterdam 
8                        Evesham
9                       Rochdale
```

I want to get something like this:

```
                   user_location country
2  Socialist Republic of Alachua ['USSR', 'United States']
3                Hérault, France ['France']
4                 Gwalior, India ['India'] 
5                Zaragoza,España ['Spain']
7                     amsterdam  ['Holland']
8                        Evesham ['United Kingdom']
9                       Rochdale ['United Kingdom', 'United States']
```

**REPREX:**

```py
import pandas as pd
import geograpy3

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'user_location': {2: 'Socialist Republic of Alachua', 3: 'Hérault, France', 4: 'Gwalior, India', 5: 'Zaragoza,España', 7: 'amsterdam ', 8: 'Evesham', 9: 'Rochdale'}})

df['country'] = df['user_location'].apply(lambda x: geograpy.get_place_context(text=x).countries if pd.notnull(x) else x)

print(df)
#>                    user_location                                            country
#> 2  Socialist Republic of Alachua  [USSR, Union of Soviet Socialist Republics, Al...
#> 3                Hérault, France                                  [France, Hérault]
#> 4                 Gwalior, India   [British Indian Ocean Territory, Gwalior, India]
#> 5                Zaragoza,España             [Zaragoza, España, Spain, El Salvador]
#> 7                     amsterdam                                                  []
#> 8                        Evesham                          [Evesham, United Kingdom]
#> 9                       Rochdale          [Rochdale, United Kingdom, United States]
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-02 by the [reprexpy package](https://github.com/crew102/reprexpy)</sup>

Comment: Include `geograpy` as a tag for your question. This will help experts to get here more often.

Comment: Unfortunately, `geograpy` is not an existing tag and I don't have enough reputation to create one :'(

Comment: added the tag and a description

Comment: if reprex is your working solution you might want to add it as your answer. Which version of geograpy did you use?

Comment: Ey @WolfgangFahl reprex strands for Reproducible Example. I'm using geography3 1.0.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

geograpy3 was not behaving correctly anymore regarding country lookup since it didn't check if None was returned by pycountry. As a committer i just fixed this.
I have added your slightly modified example (to avoid the pandas import) as a unit test case:

```
def testStackoverflow62152428(self):
        '''
        see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62152428/extracting-country-information-from-description-using-geograpy?noredirect=1#comment112899776_62152428
        '''
        examples={2: 'Socialist Republic of Alachua', 3: 'Hérault, France', 4: 'Gwalior, India', 5: 'Zaragoza,España', 7: 'amsterdam ', 8: 'Evesham', 9: 'Rochdale'}  
        for index,text in examples.items():
            places=geograpy.get_geoPlace_context(text=text)
            print("example %d: %s" % (index,places.countries))
```

and the result is now:

```
example 2: ['United States']
example 3: ['France']
example 4: ['British Indian Ocean Territory', 'India']
example 5: ['Spain', 'El Salvador']
example 7: []
example 8: ['United Kingdom']
example 9: ['United Kingdom', 'United States']
```

indeed there is room for improvement for example 5. I have added an issue https://github.com/somnathrakshit/geograpy3/issues/7 - please stay tuned ...

Comment: @TitoSanz you might want to check out the new locate functionality see https://geograpy3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/tests/test_locator.html#TestLocator.testExamples